# Create a multistep Webform and set to "non-linear" with sidebar showing which steps have been completed?

Tags: webforms

I have several steps in my Webform that require certain values to pass each step.

This is done by Webform Validation and seems to work fine, however how can I turn the Webform into something that's "non-linear" allowing users to jump to any page they want to complete with ease.

Ideally I'd want to move the titles for each multistep page to a sidebar menu which would show the status of whether that page is completed or not.

Is there any modules that do something similar already?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for how to create this functionality, and found this on the drupal site [Link for creating multi-step webforms](http://drupal.org/node/324779)

Comment: Well I have a multistep Webform already set-up, but I don't want the "next" and "back" buttons. I want each step to act like a page, and then to use a sidebar menu that shows the steps but set that menu to use a different CSS class depending on whether that step/page is completed (validated).